# Anyone else having this issue running jQuery and LESS stylesheets?

Tags: jquery, css, html, less

I'm using a LESS stylesheet and jQuery for scripting, but the LESS.js file seems to be conflicting with jQuery.  For instance, once I place the external links in the header the browser no longer recognizes the `$` identifier for jQuery and ends up breaking my scripting.  Has anyone else had this issue?  If so, have you been able to fix it, and how did you get it to work?  Here's the head structure in my html document.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/style.less.css" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css">
    <script>
        less = {
            env: "development",
            logLevel: 2,
            async: false,
            fileAsync: false,
            poll: 1000,
            functions: {},
            dumpLineNumbers: "comments",
            relativeUrls: false,
            globalVars: {
                var1: '"string value"',
                var2: 'regular value'
            },
        };
    </script>
    <script src="js/less-1.7.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.2.0.3.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `script.js` is your code, it should come after `jquery.2.0.3.js`. The `$` variable is only available for use after jQuery has been included in the page.

```
<script src="js/jquery.2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gotcha.  Thank you.  Guess my inability to recognize that simple error is an indication of how my day's gonna go.  Thanks again.